# Find top-level directory from subdirectory on Linux in Python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, directory, os.path

I am creating various HTML file parts, image thumbnails etc. from within a `CodeIgniter` application tree using cron-scheduled `Python 2.7` programs on Linux. The actual Python programs exist under the `CodeIgniter` tree in a subdirectory one level below the application directory as follows.

```
codeigniter/web-root 
    |
    application
    |   |    
    |   scripts
    |   |   |
    |   |   my-program.py
    |   | 
    |   database
    |       |
    |       database.sqlite 
    images
```

I want to determine the `codeigniter/web-root` directory from within `my-program.py` using methods from the `os.path` module. However, the absolute path to the `codeigniter/web-root` is different on the development and production environments so I prefer not to hardwire this path information into the Python program itself.

The current script(s) use the following construct to determine the absolute path of "codeigniter/web-root" which is two directory levels above the script itself in both environments.

```
#!/bin/env python2.7

import os.path

ci_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```

Is there a cleaner way to determine the top level(ci_root) directory without using multiple `os.path.dirname` calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os.path
print os.path.abspath(__file__+'/../../..')   # the directory three levels up
```

I was pleasantly surprised that

- abspath() managed to parse correctly, without using os.path.join()
- We didn't have to strip out the filename before we build the path

For cross platform compatibility if abspath's parsing does not work, we could use something less readable, e.g.

- os.path.sep instead of '/'
- os.path.join()

Answer (score 1):

Find the real path based on the relative path of "up three directories," and extract the last part of that real path.

[Edit: In response to your comment I have revised this. In my opinion it is getting complex
enough that your chain of `dirname`'s is better. At least it is easy to understand what it happening.]

```
from os import path as p
_, ci_root = p.split(p.abspath(p.join(__file__, '../../..')))
```

Comment: shtako... you were faster :) +1

Comment: That actually causes it too jump up one too many directory levels. Is there a means to perform this always based off of the __file__ attribute so that starting directory does not impact the execution of the program. For instance, if I wanted to execute this from my $HOME directory in addition to the cronjob, the programs will break because a relative path is specified.